# ml type analysis of the fold function

Tags: types, ml

Can anyone please explain to me how to figure out the type of the following function, fold, as defined below?

```
fun fold func [] base = base
|   fold func (x::xs) base = fold func xs (func x base);
```

My answer is 'c->'a list->'b->'b, but I see that after plugging in the code to my SML program that the type should actually be ('a->'b->'b)->'a list->'b->'b.

I understand where the 'a list->'b->'b comes from, but the first part is confusing me.  Is it because func takes two arguments, an 'a and a 'b, and returns the type of base, which is 'b?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it because func takes two arguments, an 'a and a 'b, and returns the type of base, which is 'b?

Yes, exactly.

If the first part were just `'c` as you first assumed, that would mean the first argument to `fold` could be any value - an `int` for example. Clearly it should not be legal to pass in an `int` (or anything else that isn't a function) as the first argument to `func`, so the first argument needs to have a type that tells the type system to only allow functions for this argument.

And in fact it should not just allow any functions, but only functions of the appropriate type. And the appropriate type for `func` is `'a -> 'b -> 'b` for the reasons you state above.